# How can i make such illustrations for youtube thumnails?

Tags: illustration

[image]
I am beginner. How can i  make such illustrations for my fitness youtube thumnails?

Comment: You can just draw it.   Use something like Photoshop or Krita (which is free) or vector software such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape (which is free).

Comment: Who would want a neck like the one on the after image?

Comment: @Wolff I'd be more concerned that my nipples fell off and bellybutton moved and shrank.

Comment: No  need to draw. Take a photo of yourself now, when you still are a beginner. Then do your exercises few days and take another photo.

Answer (score 1):

You **draw** them using the tool of your choice - digital or analog.

You can always use a piece of paper and scan any drawing afterwards (or take a photo). And practically *any* graphics software has tools to facilitate images such as these.

If you are seeking some sort of automated, non-skilled, solution. I suppose any of the current artificial intelligence image generators *could* possibly come up with something similar. But you will need to experiment with various AI prompts to get what you want.